# Folder became File during copy

Tags: cmd.exe, copy

I wanted to copy the contents of the desktop folder to my usb during windows setup in the cmd prompt. I used the command "copy desktop D:\desktop" and it listed out the files in the folder as it copied. I verified by "D:" "dir" and it listed desktop so I thought all was good.

The folder is now on my usb listed as a 1.52mb file with no type. If I open the file in hex workshop, I can see it does contain the contents of the desktop folder, but I don't know if there's even a way to recover it. Any ideas?

only 2 files are important for me to access, one of them being an html file and the other a txt file, of which I know the filenames. I just don't really know how to use a hex editor.

next time I'll remember to use xcopy :P

Comment: Silly question, but you can't simply open the folder?

Comment: Unfortunately no... its not seen as a folder, its just seen as a typeless file. If I open it in 7zip there is an xml inside but it can't be extracted. I would think the command would have just failed in the first place. Oh well, in this case it was no big deal, I always have a backup. Just something to keep in mind I guess!